# Azure Function called from Azure API Management CORS Error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

I've created a simple **HTTP Trigger** function and linked it to the **API management**.

Then I've set the **Cors policy** in the **API Management** like this:

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <cors>
        <allowed-origins>
            <origin>*</origin>
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
            <method>*</method>
        </allowed-methods>
    </cors>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <forward-request />
</backend>
<outbound />
<on-error />
```

When I call it from a blazor wasm, it gives the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://example-api.azure-api.net/teste/Teste' from origin 'https://localhost:5001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

A few points to notice:

- When I call 'https://example-api/teste/Teste' directly from the browser, it works.
- When I call the function from blazor wasm directly (without API management) it works.
- When I call 'https://example-api/teste/Teste' from blazor wasm it gives the **Cors Error** mentioned.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Registered with Azure AD to protect the Azure function and then

1. Configure **Redirect URI** > Select **Web** > type `<app-url>/.auth/login/aad/callback`.
2. Click on **Implicit grant flow** > define API scope and copy it
3. Set up API permissions. Permissions to access function should be granted to your client application.

[image]

- In your App Service app, enable Azure Active Directory and enable the CORS policy in Azure Function App.

**Code**

1. Create the Custom class and name it as `AuthorizationMessageHandler`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication;

public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider, 
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
            authorizedUrls: new[] { "<your function app url>" },
            scopes: new[] { "<the function app  API scope your define>" });
    }
}
```

2. In `Program.cs` file:

```
 public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");
             // register CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler 
            builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
            // configure httpclient
            // call the following code please add packageMicrosoft.Extensions.Http 3.1.0
            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client =>
              client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<your function app url>"))
                    .AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();
            // register the httpclient
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
             .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));
            // configure Azure AD auth
            builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
            {
                builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
                options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("<the function app  API scope your define>");


            });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
```

3. API Calling:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>Call Azure Function</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server. </p>

<p>Result: @forecasts</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="CallFun">Call Function</button>

@code {
    private string forecasts;

    protected async Task CallFun()
    {
        forecasts = await Http.GetStringAsync("api/http");
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already can call the function directly as in your example. The problem occurs when using "Azure API Management" as a gateway.

Comment: @GuilhermeMolin, while calling the API, are you getting that error?

Comment: Calling the Azure Function directly works "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/Teste" using the "azure api management" as gateway doesn't "example-api.azure-api.net/teste/Teste" which calls the former.